# Key error in pandas dataframe with Twitter data

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

I have been trying to transfer some data from I collected with the Tweepy package into a Pandas dataframe. This code worked in PyScripter, but when I try to run it in PyCharm, I get an error (" KeyError: 'user' "). My code is below, does anyone know why it would work in one IDE and not another? Also, any ideas at how I could get it to work in PyCharm?

```
# Import data manipulation tools
import json
import pandas

# Read in previously collected data into an array we call 'Tweets'
file_name = 'tweet_test1b.txt'
tweets_data = []
tweets_data_file = open(file_name, 'r')
for line in tweets_data_file:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)


tweet_frame = pandas.DataFrame()
tweet_frame['user'] = map(lambda data: data['user'], tweets_data)
```

Comment: what does your df look like?

Comment: Hmm, if I'm not wrong, based on the code above, it should just be an empty frame, right? Do you mean what does the data look like? If so, it is a dictionary full of strings.

Comment: Missed it was empty,  your error is from `data['user']`, you must have a dict that does not have the key. It has nothing to do with pandas I imagine. try `data.get('user')` passing whatever default value you like and it will be clear what is wrong when you see the df, or else use a for loop and iterate over the dicts then you will know exactly what dict us causing the issue